# Wireless display via Miracast without redirecting audio

Tags: audio, hdmi

I have an AnyCast device attached to my HDMI monitor (which has no audio capability).
This is working fine with Miracast from my Samsung A71, using 'Separate App Sounds' to push the audio out through the 'phone speaker.

I also have a cheap tablet (DragonTouch K10, Android 8.1.0).

If I cast to the AnyCast via the DragonTouch's wireless display support, the display works a treat but the audio disappears (presumably it is being routed to non-existent HDMI audio support).

Is there a generic Android equivalent to the Samsung 'Separate App Sounds', or any other suitable 'audio switch' capability, and, if so, where can I find this? I have tried a few apparently relevant Google Play apps but they just tinker with the volume and/or swap between speaker and headphones.

Comment: I am amazed that no-one else sees Android's lack of built in ability to switch audio output as a problem... I clearly need to learn Android programming.

Comment: No answer to award the bounty to